# deprecated warning while compiling

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

i have a question regarding development environments settings.
 i am trying to see if there is any possibility to make a compilation warning in a `development environment(eclipse,android studio)`for android applications using a deprecated feature(could be a method , constructor or whatever you can think of ). until now i am working manually to find the use of this deprecated features , and my boss asked me to look for an automatic settings in my idea  ...

so lets say for a specific code :

```
 protected void onPrepareDialog(int paramInt, Dialog paramDialog)
  {
    try
    {
      super.onPrepareDialog(paramInt, paramDialog);
      AlertDialog localAlertDialog = (AlertDialog)paramDialog;
      localAlertDialog.setTitle("Passphrase required");
      ((TextView)localAlertDialog.findViewById(2131230727)).setText(Preferences.getConfigName(this, getConfigFile()));
      Button localButton = localAlertDialog.getButton(-3);
      if (this.mOpenVpnService != null);
      for (boolean bool = true; ; bool = false)
      {
        localButton.setEnabled(bool);
        return;
      }
```

i have several deprecated features here , and android studio declares it , but what i need is a configuration for this warning to be automated and save me the need of walking through  each class manually ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Select **Analyze > Inspect Code** to run lint on your project. It should detect any deprecated methods, as well as others common mistakes in your project.

You can select "Run inspection by name" and there you can find "Deprecated API usage" (Java / Code maturity issues).

Comment: When I did this it listed about  20 main categories with dozens of subcategories and issues, including 22512 for spelling. There is no 'Depreciated' category for the first level of 20 or so classifications, you can find it buried in Code Maturity Issues/Depreciated API Usage. This is important enough it should be up in the main categories a depreciated API can hang your compile at 'transformdexfordebug'.

Comment: You can select "Run inspection by name" and there you can find "Deprecated API usage" (Java / Code maturity issues).

Comment: This selection is not available in Android Studio 3.4.1 and Lint did find a lot of things but not that `Deprecation Warning` from my compiler. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best solution is add this lines in the file build.gradle(project:appname)

```
allprojects {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

Then all the deprecated methods in the java files appear in the build tab:
[deprecated api tab android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZwzB.jpg)

This works on gradle 5.1.1